# Are there functions with a Fourier transform but no Laplace transform?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, distribution-theory, convolution

Let

$$A = \text{the collection of functions with a Fourier transform}$$

and

$$B = \text{the collection of functions with a Laplace transform.}$$

What is the relationship between $A$ and $B$? Based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Fourier_transform) Wikipedia page, any $f \in A$ has a Laplace transform that converges along the imaginary axis, so $A \subset B$. If this is correct, I don't understand why we learn about the Laplace transform separate from the Fourier transform. Is there a sense in which $A \nsubseteq B$? **To put it another way, would it ever make sense to say "The Laplace transform does not exist, so we must take the Fourier Transform" for any common definitions of the Laplace and Fourier transforms?**

I can suggest two possibilities that may lead to $A \nsubseteq B$:

1. Higher dimensional generalizations of the transforms may lead to $A \nsubseteq B$
2. Consideration of non-functions (distributions) may lead to $A \nsubseteq B$

Comment: I think the density of the Cauchy distribution will do: it has a Fourier transform b ut not finite Laplace transform.

Comment: Are you referring the unilateral Laplace transform $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\,e^{-s x}\,dx$ or bilateral Laplace transform $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-s x}\,dx$?

Comment: @StevenClark both. The OP refers to the bilateral transform, but I tried to leave the floor open if there is anything to be said about the unilateral transform.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Hello my friend.  How are you?  Just curious ... why does the Cauchy PDF have no LT?  It is $L^1$.

Comment: Hi @MarkViola, the Cauchy density $f$  has of course a Fourier transform, but it has no finite moments $\int |x| f(x)\, dx=\infty$ So the integral $\int e^{-sx} f(x)\, dx=\infty$ for $s$ real and different from $0$. That is what I had in mind.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I thought the pdf was $$\frac{\gamma/\pi}{(x-x_0)^2+\gamma^2}.$$  Certainly this is integrable even though its moments don't exist.  So, it has a LT for all $\text{R}(s)\ge0$

Comment: @MarkViola: I have not done any pencil-paper verification but I think that $\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-st}\frac{dt}{t^2+1}\,dt=\infty$.

Comment: Ah.  You're talking about the bilateral LT.  I was referring to the unilateral LT.  The bilateral LT should be fine on $\mathbb{S}$.

Comment: @MarkViola: exactly! For finite nonnegative measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R})$ I think of the Laplace transform as $L\mu(s):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-sx}\mu(dx)$. Maybe the OP has something else in mind.

Comment: @OliverDíaz And the LT exist for purely imaginary $s$, which is a FT.

Comment: @MarkViola: Sure, for $L\mu(is)=\mathcal{F}\mu(s)$.